# why am i getting undefined in req.body while updating

Tags: mysql, node.js

i have succsesfully inserted a colors and  is succsefully showing in other routes but when i want to update it shows me the follwing  error . I have stored color as char(7) . What am i doing wrong

code: 'ER_DATA_TOO_LONG',
errno: 1406,
sqlState: '22001',
index: 0,
sql: "UPDATE note SET heading='fatima', body='sami', color='undefined'  WHERE noteid = '56921193-c950-11eb-aa7a-b8ac6fc723ed'"

```
router.put('/:id', isLoggedIn, isAuthor, async (req, res) => {
  let color =  req.body.ColorInput 
  const sql = "UPDATE note SET heading='" + req.body.heading + "', body='" + req.body.body + "', color='" + color + "'  WHERE noteid = '" + req.params.id + "'"
  await db.query(sql, (err, rows) => {
    if (!err) {
      req.flash('success', 'Successfully update the Note!');
      res.redirect(`/notes/${req.params.id}`)
    }
    else
      console.log(err);
  });
})
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what `console.log(req.body);` outputs when added to your function above `let color = …`

Comment: Hi dusthaines thanks for comment i have resolved my problem